# query on view with where scan all tables and than execute where

Tags: sql, postgresql, view

I created a view which is union of few tables.

```
create view report as
select date,a,b,0,0 from table1
union all
select date,0,0,c,d from table2
```

I select with where on dates:

```
select * from report where date = '2013-01-01'
```

I look on the explain and i see that the where filter is execute at the end of the execution (after the append). How can i create the view in such a way that the where will be on each table before the append.

thank you

Using in postgres9.1

Explain :: (tables and columns renamed in order to protect privacy)

```
"Aggregate  (cost=127286.88..127286.89 rows=1 width=8)"
"  ->  Subquery Scan on external_reports  (cost=0.00..127254.46 rows=12969 width=8)"
"        Filter: (external_reports.date = '2012-09-09 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)"
"        ->  Append  (cost=0.00..94831.27 rows=2593855 width=54)"
"              ->  Result  (cost=0.00..71.38 rows=10 width=112)"
"                    ->  Append  (cost=0.00..71.38 rows=10 width=112)"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on report1  (cost=0.00..14.26 rows=2 width=112)"
"                                Filter: ((x)::text = 'ADS'::text)"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on report2  (cost=0.00..14.26 rows=2 width=112)"
"                                Filter: ((x)::text = 'ADS2'::text)"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on report3  (cost=0.00..14.26 rows=2 width=112)"
"                                Filter: ((x)::text = 'ADS3'::text)"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on report4  (cost=0.00..14.26 rows=2 width=112)"
"                                Filter: ((x)::text = 'ADS4'::text)"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on report5  (cost=0.00..14.26 rows=2 width=112)"
"                                Filter: ((x)::text = 'ADS5'::text)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on report6  (cost=0.00..65421.34 rows=2459934 width=54)"
"              ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 7"  (cost=0.00..4739.22 rows=133911 width=52)"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on report___  (cost=0.00..3400.11 rows=133911 width=52)"
```

Comment: Can you post the explain please? Also. Are both date columns the same type?

Comment: @JakubKania I add the explain. By the way what is the meaning of *SELECT* 7 i dont have such select

Comment: No idea to be honest. But what's the type of the date columns? Are they all timestamp_without_time_zone?

Comment: It is doing a `where x = 'ADSX'` in each `reportX` table. Show the output of `=> \d reportX`

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto didnt understand you can elaborate more. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no way to do this.
Since that each select is separated and union is done after the select , so where will be done on each select.